# putting ad in drawerlayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

The problem is that I can't put ad@m ad in drawerlayout.
I want to show ad@m ad on every screen.
If I put codes that is

Can you help me? Thanks so much in advance! :)

This is my code below.

main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

      <net.daum.adam.publisher.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        clientId="test"
        requestInterval="60"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is error message.

```
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Moumi_Social/com.Moumi_Social.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class net.daum.adam.publisher.AdView
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class net.daum.adam.publisher.AdView
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1915)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at com.Moumi_Social.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    ... 11 more
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.daum.adam.publisher.AdView
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
04-02 15:06:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    ... 22 more
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `DrawerLayout` -- you will get the same error if you use `net.daum.adam.publisher.AdView` anywhere in your app, as the class cannot be found. There is something wrong in how you have integrated their library into your project.

Comment: Yes! You're correct. I sovled it by changing library priotiy order. Thanks.

Comment: Delete your question